# How do I use a function from one js file inside another js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two js files in a structure that can be simplified to this:

js1:

```
$(function() {
   function f1 {
         f2();
    }
});
```

js2:

```
$(function() {
     function f2() {
     }
});
```

Do i have to declare all my functions in js2 in a global object to do this or is there an easier way? I'm currently getting Uncaught reference error because js1 can't find js2's function.

Both script files are included in the page header.

Comment: just include js2 inside js1..

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla — That won't work. They are still in different scopes that don't have access to each other.

Comment: I recommend following one of the [UMD module patterns](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) - amdWebGlobal is normally what I start with; note it will work even without AMD, and can be trimmed down even further.

Answer (score 1):

> Do i have to declare all my functions in js2 in a global object to do this

Yes

Or, at least, there must be a global object via which access to them is possible (e.g. `foo.bar.baz.f2`).

```
var foo = {};
$(function() {
     function f2() {
     }
     foo.bar = { baz: { f2: f2 } };
});
```

Comment: can i get a simplified example? Is it:
$(function() {
 foo = { };
  foo.f2 = f2();
}

Answer (score 0):

Although the simple answer to your question is just to concatenate the two files or to define the functions as a global variable or to use a global namespace, I think it's also appropriate to mention the solutions that are most popular in the current state of javascript development.

Mainly you need to read more about javascript modules ( most popular formats are [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) and [CommonJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html) ) and structure your app according to them.

Using tools such as [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) you might get the proper solution of your problem and mainly wrap your functions inside modules, like this :

```
/* module f1 ( file f1.js ) */
module.exports = function() { ... }

/* module f2 ( file f2.js ) */
f1 = require('./f1');
f2 = function() { ... /* you can access f1 function here */ };
```

And with AMD format will look like this :

```
/* module f1 ( file f1.js ) */
define('f1', function() { ... });

/* module f2 ( file f2.js ) */
define('f2', ['f1'], function(f1) { /* you can access f1 function here */ });
```

and later in your html you can simply do

```
<script src='requirejs.js'></script>
<script src='f1.js'></script>
<script src='f2.js'></script>
<script>require('f2');</script>
```

**NOTE** : This answer is not the simplest solution for your problem, it more pretends to be the proper one.